# Modelsim Warning: (vlog-2083) <protected>(<protected>): Carriage return (0x0D) is not followed by a newline (0x0A)

Tags: intel, fpga, modelsim, intel-fpga

I'm getting this warnings, that are very annoying because it floods all the transcript, and I don't know why they appear just after "loading/running" the file C:/intelfpga_pro/18.0/quartus/eda/sim_lib/mentor/twentynm_hssi_atoms_ncrypt.v -work twentynm_hssi

How can I get rid of this warnings?

In the original Intel forum post is attached the full transcript:

https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P000040wKRoSAM/modelsim-warning-vlog2083-protectedprotected-carriage-return-0x0d-is-not-followed-by-a-newline-0x0a

thanks

Comment: Do you have broken text files that have an embedded `\r` alone?  It sounds like the program you're using wants DOS line endings.  If they're supposed to be newlines (like if this file was from a classic-Mac?), maybe `tr '\r' '\n' < input > output` or any equivalent way of converting line endings.

Comment: I've checked the file with notepad++ and it's a compiled file with the corresponding "\r\n" at the end of all the lines

Comment: But are there any stray `\r` characters *not* at the ends of lines?  This program is claiming there are, so maybe use a hex editor or something else to search for them.

Comment: I've done a recheck of the files and made the necessary changes so now all the lines on twentynm_hssi_atoms_ncrypt.v and twentynm_hip_atoms_ncrypt.v end with \r\n and there is no \r alone. Also I'm trying to contact mentor but for some reason I can do an SR to all the products of mentor I have license but not for modelsim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answer from Mentor,

the problem, as Peter Cordes said, is the \r alone but this happens inside the protected compiled code, so only intel can solve this warning.

Meanwhile I can suppress this warning by adding the “-suppress 2083” in the vlog line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Modelsim SE 10.7 issue as Modelsim 10.2c (which I still have) compiles the file without any issues.

H:\Vendors>vlog H:\Vendors\intelFPGA\18.0\quartus\eda\sim_lib\mentor\twentynm_hssi_atoms_ncrypt.v
Model Technology ModelSim DE vlog 10.2c Compiler 2013.07 Jul 18 2013

Top level modules:

So you could try an older version of Modelsim SE and report this bug to Mentor (it also fails with Questa 10.7b).

Good luck,
Hans.

Comment: Part of the previous comment was answering you, I'm trying to contact mentor but for some reason I can do an SR to all the products my organization have license but not for modelsim, I have send a service request to the TI department and when they solve this issue I will be able to talk with someone of mentor.